# @Transactional is not rollback in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-transactions, transactional

I am having the spring boot application with the following method:

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
    private void saveAndUpdatepMSTAndRollUpEntries(pMST newpMSTEntry,
                                                           pMST existingpMSTEntry,
                                                           List<sPTrans> sPTranss,
                                                           List<sPTrans> sPTransUpdatedFlagList) {

        if(!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(existingpMSTEntry))
            databaseService.deleteProcessedpMST(existingpMSTEntry);
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(sPTransUpdatedFlagList))
            databaseService.saveProcessedsPTransFeedWithUpdatedFlag(sPTransUpdatedFlagList);
        if(!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(newpMSTEntry))
            databaseService.saveProcessedpMSTTableEntry(newpMSTEntry);
    }
```

and my database service contains the code as follows:

```
public class DatabaseService {


    private PosMonthlyStRepository posMonthlyStRepository;
    private ScmsaPosTransRollupRepository scmsaPosTransRollupRepository;

    public DatabaseService(PosMonthlyStRepository posMonthlyStRepository) {
        this.posMonthlyStRepository = posMonthlyStRepository;

    }

    public void deleteProcessedpMST(pMST objpMST){
        posMonthlyStRepository.delete(objpMST);
    }
   public void saveProcessedsPTransFeedWithUpdatedFlag(List<sPTrans> sPTransssPTransUpdatedFlagList) {
        scmsaPosTransRollupRepository.save(sPTransUpdatedFlagList);
    }

    public void saveProcessedpMSTTableEntry((pMST objpMST)  {
        posMonthlyStRepository.save(objpMST);
    }
 }
```

But whenever the exception occurs the transaction is not rolling back, Can anyone please suggest me what am doing wrong here.

Comment: Judging from the fact that the method is `private` you are internally calling this method. As Spring uses proxies to implement AOP (and yes that is used for transactions) the call doesn't pass through the proxy and basically the `@Transactional` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you please suggest what else I can do. But all my databaseService class methods are public only.

Comment: No they aren't this one is clearly `private`... Your unit-of-work (probably the outer most method) must be `@Transactional` to have a single unit of work to either succeed or fail.

Comment: Why would you specify `rollbackOn = Exception.class`? Your method doesn't throw any checked exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

If you are calling `saveAndUpdatepMSTAndRollUpEntries` this method from the same class as mentioned below then `@Transactional` wont work.

```
EG:
Class Sample{

public void someMethod()
{
saveAndUpdatepMSTAndRollUpEntries(); // Wont rollback
}
private void  saveAndUpdatepMSTAndRollUpEntries()
{

}
}
```

This is  because spring uses proxied objects for Transactional and you are not calling the transactional method using proxied object instead `this` object is using.

For the thing to work you can call as below:

```
Class Sample{

public void someMethod()
{
Sample obj=ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(Sample.class);
obj.saveAndUpdatepMSTAndRollUpEntries(); // will rollback since you are calling using proxied spring bean.
}
private void  saveAndUpdatepMSTAndRollUpEntries()
{

}
}
```

I guess this is the issue-

Added applicationContextprovider

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  public ApplicationContext getContext() {
    return applicationContext;
  }
}
```

Comment: @kaviya.P Then probably some other issue. Post your entire code, i mean the caller method. Probably you have to use `propagation.nested` for transactional

Comment: I have added it .Can you please check it and help me to get out of it

Comment: ApplicationContextProvider which package STS/ eclipse is not showing any suggestion

Comment: Thanks, man. I was searching all over. application context provider solved. Any blog or documentation about these areas?